# Cold weather idling issue, white smoke, black soot and loss in power

Tags: engine, exhaust, jeep

I have a 1976 cj7. I recieved it as a gift from my Dad in March this year. I absolutely love this Jeep and have been driving it as often as possible. It had a really bad idle and severe exhaust/fuel smell. I had to apply pressure on the gas peddle when sitting at red lights so it would not stall. It often stalled while driving and the engine was very loud. I took it to a reputable shop in town and planned to replace manifold gasket. Upon doing that they found the exhaust manifold had a crack. 1k later it now has a new exhaust manifold and was running quiet, smoother and no gas smell. New problem: now it is starting to shoot out soot from the exhaust accompanied by small but consistent white smoke. Idle is better however when driving it is hard to get it from 1st to 2nd gear - like a loss of power. And the stalling is slowly coming back. Is this the cold weather or more engine issues? It has gotten colder since the new exhaust manifold.